# I can not call function inside button <a href="">

Tags: function, button, call

I'm working in edit mode (contenteditable=true), I need to call the function inside the link but it does not respond.

Can be done? I need it

Note: I canceled the buttons to call the function, but it does not work either:

My HTML:

```
<body>
  <a href="link.html"><i class="miniButton">Inside</i>LINK Think</a>
  <div id="message"></div>
  <i class="miniButton">out link button</i>
</body>
```

Mi Code:

```
$("body").on("click",'a', function() {
    return false;
});

$(document).on("click",'.miniButton', function() {
    $("#message").html("Good Job");
});
```

Mi jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1go4ecdj/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return false` on all anchor elements was preventing the click event from reaching the .miniButton element inside of it.  If you need to prevent navigation, you can use `preventDefault()`  on the event instead of cancelling it altogether:

```js
$("body").on("click",'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
});

$(document).on("click",'.miniButton', function() {
    $("#message").html("Good Job");
});
```

```css
body{padding: 3em  ;}
a{
  color: White;
  background: SteelBlue;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
i{
  color: White;
  background: Black;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#message{
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  background: #FFEEAA;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 160px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="link.html"><i class="miniButton">Inside</i>LINK Think</a>
  <div id="message"></div>
  <i class="miniButton">out link button</i>
```

Comment: It was something so simple. Thanks @Daniel Beck

Answer (score 2):

Instead of return false you should try this.

```
$("a").on("click", function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: But the link is activated and it goes to another page

Comment: ooh, I'd roll back that edit; your original answer was correct.

Comment: Sorry I did not add the event, I did not see it. cry

thanks for your help. @Markus

Comment: Then I‘ve understand the comment from the author wrong. Can I reset the last edit?

Comment: yep, hit the "edited ___ min ago" link, find the edit you want to roll back to, and hit "rollback"